# Get list of class attribute references python

Tags: python, pointers, python-decorators

Is it possible to get list of object references using a python object?
I'm trying to get a list of object attribute references in order to do something similar to the example below:

```
class Test:
def __init__(self):
    self._foo = 1
    self._bar = 2

@property
def foo(self):
    return self._foo

@foo.setter
def foo_setter(self, foo):
    self._foo = foo

@property
def bar(self):
    return self._bar

@bar.setter
def bar_setter(self, bar):
    self._bar = bar

def att_list(self):
    return [
        self.bar_setter,
        self.foo_setter
    ]

def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return f'foo: {self._foo}, bar: {self._bar}'

test = Test()
att_list = test.att_list()
print(test)
for att in att_list:
    if att > 1:
        att += 1

print(test)
```

Idealy this test would print out:

```
foo: 1, bar: 2
foo: 1, bar: 3
```

As you can see I want to get a list of the references to the object's attributes (in this case foo and bar) in order to not only be able to read them, but also write to them, so far I have tried to pass the setter function of the attributes but this only returnes the value.

Answer (score -1):

To pull all the attributes and methods from a class, you normally use the builtin dir() function. You can then filter that to some criteria based on your particular use case. For example:

```
class A:
    x = 7

attrs = [attr for attr in dir(A) if not attr.startswith('__')] #Filtering out hidden.
```